# How to change the font title in the text editor of the ribbon when editing a page?

Tags: 2013, ribbon, sharepoint-server

I found a way to do so in SharePoint 2010 (see [this link](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Use-font-face-in-Rich-Text-Editor-of-SharePoint-2010.aspx)) but this method no longer seems to work with SharePoint 2013. In 2010, it changes the name of the font you're overriding in the drop-down as well, but this does not happen in 2013.

I added this to my "fonts.css" file:

```
@import url("arial.ttf");

.ms-rteFontFace-4 {
    -ms-name: "Arial";
    font-family: "Arial", arial, helvetica, sans-serif !important; 
}
```

I chose to change .ms-rteFontFace-4 because that one was originally Comic Sans. Now, the text does show up in Arial, but in the drop-down with the font options it still shows the name "Comic Sans" instead of "Arial". I'd like it to show "Arial".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this procedure?

http://knowledge.zomers.eu/SharePoint/Pages/How-to-add-custom-styles-to-the-ribbon-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx

I am exploring it to add new text styles.

Also the css class in SP 2013 may have changed.  You might need to use the developer tools in IE/Chrome (F12) to track down the new css class name.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I used that link yes, so far with success! I now just use predefined styles for styling pages. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome,  Glad that helped you out.